# Bat Script Scheduler Strange Characters

Tags: batch, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to make a batch script that creates a scheduled task and then runs another bat (without UCA) but the task is being created with strange characters which then prevents me from running it.

```
SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN “clean” /TR “C:clean.bat” /ST 09:00
schtasks /run /tn "clean"
pause
```

That creates a schedule with called ôcleanö

Comment: The code in your example uses non-standard double-quote characters `“ ”` (as used in documents) on the first line, though the second line correctly uses `"` (0x22).

Comment: Additionally, you have `C:clean.bat` where I think that should be `C:\clean.bat` so you are missing a backslash too—it may not make any difference on the root of the "C" drive so also consider putting that in `C:\scripts\clean.bat` instead as sometimes being on the root of the "C" drive rather than within a folder can cause problems due to root level security of the "C" drive in particular. Easy enough to test, change, etc. Good Luck!